# UITest UIAccessibility hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I have set the `isAccessibilityElement` flag to `true` on a parent view (in my case it's a `UICollectionViewCell`) and now all of its children aren't accessible for VoiceOver which is exactly what I want. I did set the `accessibilityIdentifiers` on the children views because I want to access them in my UITest. The problem is that the children views aren't visible in the accessibility hierarchy after setting this flag to `true`. If I set the flag to `false` they do become accessible in my UITests but VoiceOver will also read them out which is not what I want.

Is there a way to get the children views to appear in UITests when the `isAccessibilityElement` property is set to `true` on the parent view?

Answer (score 0):

In the build settings, use a preprocessor Macro on your UITests Target, such as `NOVOICE=1`.  Look for that macro, similar to how people will make a `DEBUG=1` or `COCOAPODS=1`.  Then use

```
 #if NOVOICE 
 // Make your changes to accessibility here.  Blind users won't hear all the levels, but your tests will
 #endif
```